# Shorten filename to n characters while preserving file extension

Tags: bash, sed, rename, cut, xargs

I'm trying to shorten a filename while preserving the extension.

I think `cut` may be the best tool to use, but I'm not sure how to preserve the file extension.

For example, I'm trying to rename `abcdefghijklmnop.txt` to `abcde.txt`

I'd like to simply lop off the end of the filename so that the total character length doesn't exceed [in this example] 5 characters.

I'm not concerned with filename clashes because my dataset likely won't contain any, and anyway I'll do a find, analyze the files, and test before I rename anything.

---

The background for this is ultimately that I want to mass truncate filenames that exceed 135 characters so that I can rsync the files to an encrypted share on a Synology NAS.

I found a good way to search for all filenames that exceed 135 characters:
`find . -type f | awk -F'/' 'length($NF)>135{print $0}'`

And I'd like to pipe that to a simple cut command to trim the filename down to size. Perhaps there is a better way than this. I found a method to [shorten filenames while preserving extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33060/linux-script-or-program-to-shorten-filenames), but I need to recurse through all sub-directories.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

**Update for clarification:**

**I'd like to use a one-liner with a syntax like this:**

`find . -type f | awk -F'/' 'length($NF)>135{print $0}' | some_code_here_to_shorten_the_filename_while_preserving_the_extension`

Comment: Is there any worry that your method of shortening might result in non-unique file names?

Comment: Great question @jas, no I'm not worried about that. With my dataset, there's not a chance that duplicate names will be created. And anyway, I will find all of the long filenames in advance and analyze them before running the script.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an explanation and/or psuedo code showing how you want to rename the files? Do you literally just want to take the first five characters of the base name + the extension?

Comment: Thanks @jas I updated the question. I'm trying to make a one-liner like this: `find . -type f  -iname "*" |awk -F'/' 'length($NF)>135{print $0}' | some_code_here` so that it recurses through the sub-directories and lops off the ends of all long filenames.

Comment: Note that `-iname "*"` has no effect; if you're not actually filtering by filename at all, you can just write `find -type f`.

Comment: Thank you @ruakh -- I'll update my question.

Comment: I think I've botched this by not asking my question clearly enough...

Comment: you got two answers, don't you think that it's a bit rude not to give any feedback to your answerers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU find and bash:

```
export n=10 # change according to your needs
find . -type f                      \
     ! -name '.*'                   \
       -regextype egrep             \
     ! -regex '.*\.[^/.]{'"$n"',}'  \
       -regex '.*[^/]{'$((n+1))',}' \
       -execdir bash -c '
    echo "PWD=$PWD"
    for f in "${@#./}"; do
        ext=${f#"${f%.*}"}
        echo mv -- "$f" "${f:0:n-${#ext}}${ext}"
    done' bash {} +
```

This will perform a dry-run, that is it shows folders followed by the commands to be executed within them. Once you're happy with its output you can drop `echo` before `mv` (and `echo "PWD=$PWD"` line too if you want) and it'll actually rename all the files whose names exceed `n` characters to names exactly of `n` characters length including extension.

Note that this excludes hidden files, and files whose extensions are equal to or longer than `n` in length (e.g. `.hidden`, `app.properties` where `n=10`).

Comment: This runs beautifully -- although it did miss one file. I've examined the results and it seems that that file has an `“` in the filename.

Comment: I'm trying to create a one-liner I can use in the terminal instead of a script.. I'm getting close with this, but it doesn't quite work (assuming all extensions are a dot and three characters):
`find . -type f  | awk -F'/' 'length($NF)>135{print $0}' | xargs -0 rename -n 's/(.*\/)(.{131}).*([.].*$)/$1$2$3/'`

Comment: @john Well, you can turn this into a one-liner (a really long one) easily, or you can save this into a script and use it directly. Wrt failure you mentioned about, I could take a look if you post the filename that causes problems

Comment: Thanks @oguz .. the filename in question is: `Governor Insists “No Insult Intended,” as “Blasphemy” Trial Begins.htm` I'm examining the filenames in SublimeText and the double quotes are slanted, as opposed to standard straight double quotes.

Also, I'm getting very close with `find . -type f | awk -F/ 'length($NF)>135{print $0}' | sed -r 's_(.*/+)(.{0,131}).*([.].*$)_\1\2\3_'` but alas I'm getting confused with the pipes and arguments, so researching how to get an `mv` in there. Thank you for your kind patience and help.  :-)

Comment: I created a file named like that and the script above renames it to Govern.htm successfully. I didn't understand your script though

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. That's very strange, I'm on a debian 9 system in case that makes a difference. Hmm...

Comment: The `“` are 3 bytes - e2 80 9c, so it will count as 3 bytes. To how many characters are you truncating? You would need an utf-8 `cut`-like tool. You could for example first substitute `“` for `"`.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Since your file are distributed in a tree of directories, you can use my original approach, but passing the script to a `sh` command passed to the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
n=5 find . -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; d=${f%/*}; b=${f##*/}; e=${b##*.}; b=${b%.*}; mv -- "$f" "$d/${b:0:n}.$e"' \;
```

### Original answer

If the filename is in a variable `x`, then `${x:0:5}.${x##*.}` should do the job.

So you might do something like

```
n=5 # or 135, or whatever you like
for f in *; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f:0:n}.${f##*.}"
done
```

Clearly this assumes that there are no clashes between the shortened names. If there are clashes, then [only one would survive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(film))! So be careful.

Comment: Sorry Enrico, I wasn't quite able to make your answer work.

Comment: @john, I have added a possible usecase.

Comment: I tried `find . -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; d=${f%/*}; b=${f##*/}; echo mv -- "$f" "$d/${b:0:135}.${b##*.}"' \;` on my test set, but it returned `sh: 1: Bad substitution`

Comment: @john, what if you use `bash` instead of `sh`? By the way, I forgot to remove `echo` (which I used to print the commands instead of executing them, just to be safe while making it up).

Comment: If I use `bash` instead of `sh` then it shortens the filename (including the extension), and then it appends the extension afterwards. For example `aaaaa136.txt` becomes `aaaaa136.tx.txt`

Comment: @john, that's because `aaaaa136.txt` is already shorter than 135 characters. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

use bash string manipulations
Details: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/string-manipulation.html.
scroll to "Substring Extraction"

example below cut filename to 10 chars preserving extension

```
~ % cat test   

rawFileName=$(basename "$1")
filename="${rawFileName%.*}"
ext="${rawFileName##*.}"

if [[ ${#filename} < 9 ]]; then
    echo ${filename:0:10}.${ext}
else
    echo $1
fi
```

And tests:

```
~ % ./test 12345678901234567890.txt
1234567890.txt
~ % ./test 1234567.txt             
1234567.txt
```